# Trying to get sqlite data using node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sqlite

I'm running into a small problem while trying to get data out of a sqlite database to a string. Here is the code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var thisShouldWork = 'Hmmm';

    db.all('select rowid as id, value from test', function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            console.log(row.id + ": " + row.value);
            thisShouldWork += 'Heeee';
        });
    });
    thisShouldWork += 'What?';
    console.log(thisShouldWork.toString());

    res.send(thisShouldWork);
});
```

The variable 'thisShouldWork' just outputs 'HmmmWhat?' at the end of this code, while it should have a few 'Heeee's in there as well. Also, console.log prints 3 lines of data so the for loop is definitely executing.
Am I doing something wrong without realizing or is there a different/better way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is executed asynchronously.

Whatever you want to do afterwards must be moved at the end of the callback:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var thisShouldWork = 'Hmmm';

    db.all('select rowid as id, value from test', function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            console.log(row.id + ": " + row.value);
            thisShouldWork += 'Heeee';
        });
        thisShouldWork += 'What?';
        console.log(thisShouldWork.toString());

        res.send(thisShouldWork);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I just tried it and its working perfectly now.